# How to restrict background data usage of individual apps in windows 8 pc?

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking

I am using windows 8 on an ASUS laptop and recently some of my apps are using huge data over a wifi network. I don't want to set the wifi network as metered as I feel in doing so my internet speed decreases when I stream video, or download something. So is there any way to restrict background data usage of individual  apps or softwares on my pc so that my data is mot wasted.(the same feature is available on any android mobile in the settings and I want the same feature on my pc) also let me know that if there is a pre-installed windows application to do that or I have to download it separately.

Comment: Just for clarification's sake: Is it Windows 8 or 8.1?

Comment: It is Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it in Control panel -> Windows Firewall -> "allow an App or Feature through Windows Firewall" (its on the left side) and there you should be able to restrict apps using internet connection. But i never actually tested this so try for yourself. Or most of apps themself have this function in their settings. Hope it helped

Comment: I don't want to completely restrict an app from using internet I just want to restrict it's background data usage. BTW your solution may also help a lot, thanks.